# FInding the percentage of a column but is not showing up

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables:

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name |
+---------+-----------+
| 6       | Alice     |
| 2       | Bob       |
| 7       | Alex      |
+---------+-----------+

+------------+---------+
| contest_id | user_id |
+------------+---------+
| 215        | 6       |
| 209        | 2       |
| 208        | 2       |
| 210        | 6       |
| 208        | 6       |
| 209        | 7       |
| 209        | 6       |
| 215        | 7       |
| 208        | 7       |
| 210        | 2       |
| 207        | 2       |
| 210        | 7       |
+------------+---------+
```

Using Int and Varchar(30)

And Im asked to find he percentage of the users registered in each contest rounded to two decimals.
Return the result table ordered by percentage in descending order.
In case of a tie, order it by contest_id in ascending order.

The expected outcome is

```
+------------+------------+
| contest_id | percentage |
+------------+------------+
| 208        | 100.0      |
| 209        | 100.0      |
| 210        | 100.0      |
| 215        | 66.67      |
| 207        | 33.33      |
+------------+------------+
```

And after a few tries I did this:

```
SELECT contest_id, ((COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) / (select count(user_id) from users))+.0) * 100 as percentage
from register
group by contest_id
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

But my outcome looks like this so far:

```
+------------+------------+
| contest_id | percentage |
+------------+------------+
| 208        | 100.0      |
| 209        | 100.0      |
| 210        | 100.0      |
| 215        | 0.0        |
| 207        | 0.0        |
+------------+------------+
```

So Im not sure why only shows results for 100%. I also used CAST but nothing changes:

```
SELECT contest_id, CAST(((COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) / (select count(user_id) from users))+.0) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) * 100 as percentage
from register
group by contest_id
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

And I get the exact same result. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Adding `.0` *after* the division is too late. `4/7=0` in `int`s. You need your division to be in decimals, not the result.

Comment: @ThomA oh ok wait I'll try that brb

Comment: @ThomA ok it works, but My new question is, Why it only works if I add the +.0 to the subquery and not the subquery AND the first count?

Comment: Because, as I mentioned, you are doing *integer* division. If you divide an integer by an integer, you *get* an integer. This is because SQL Server uses strong typing. If you want a decimal, you need to change at least one of the values to a decimal *first*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add .0 for first value

```sql
SELECT contest_id, ((COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)+.0) / (select count(user_id) from @users)) * 100 as percentage
from @register
group by contest_id
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```